# return the column name from a table where a specific value in any row were found with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a table are different value. However there are equal values in other columns from other rows (First = Header/Column Name):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |     B            |     C            |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          100        |     200          |     300          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          400        |     100          |     500          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          600        |     700          |     800          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

To print all rows with a specific value like 100 i use following python code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='test1')

dfObject = df[df.isin([100]).any(axis=1)]

print(dfObject)
```

reusulting in an output like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          A          |     B            |     C            |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          100        |     200          |     300          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          400        |     100          |     500          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Is there any way to print only the column names where the specific value is in like this (also with distinct):

```
|---------------------|
|          A          |
|---------------------|
|          B          |
|---------------------|
```

Comment: you can just store the column names print(df.columns.values) in  a list and print.

Comment: You should clarify your question a bit, look at distinct answers below.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke the first answer is exactly what i was looking for and it took only a few minutes for anky_91 to get the point. Based on that i do have a different opinion on restating the answer. And since i was searching for a solution for quite a while i guess this could help others too. sad to see the many downvotes.

Comment: Except he added `IIUC` which means `If I understand correctly`. This does not indicate he thinks this question is well posed either. Glad you got the solution you were after though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
df.columns[df.eq(100).any()]

#Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

To Get output as series, call `pd.Series()` : `pd.Series(df.columns[df.eq(100).any()])`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `columns` attribute like  this:

`df[df.isin([100]).any(axis=1)].columns`